# ZF2 Super Globals or alternative

Tags: php, templates, module, zend-framework2

I'm working on a development envioment. This envioment usually harbors more than one design an i would like to be able to define the viewscripts depending on the envioment/design.

first i was thinking to use super globals but after reading on the net that other developers tells you to refrain from it.

I want to ask

what way should i be doing this?

my thought was to define a super global (still not sure how either) like:

somefile

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$splitdomain = explode(".",$url);
define('__SUBDOMAIN__', $splitdomain[0]);
```

and then in the module config

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __SUBDOMAIN__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/view/',
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Comment: That `somefile` is definitely `public/index.php`.

Comment: When i was reading around the Internet a lot of people said that this is not good practise what your opinion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of configurations, and keeping to the suggested practise i added

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$splitdomain = explode(".",$url);
define('__SUBDOMAIN__', $splitdomain[0]);
define('__THEME__', $splitdomain[0]);
```

in the top of application.config.php.

I the changed

```
'config_glob_paths' => array(
    'config/autoload/{,modules/*/}{,*.}{global,local}.php',
),
```

(My own idea to keep track of the modules easier)
Then i created

```
config/modules/Application/local.php
```

here i added the parsing of the design templates, layouts etc.

```
<?php

namespace Application;

/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../views/designs/'.__THEME__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../views/designs/'.__THEME__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../views/designs/'.__THEME__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../views/designs/'.__THEME__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../../../../views/designs/'.__THEME__.'/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I then did the same to the other modules and that way I can separate designs for different clients without having do deploy an entire system.